# finding the center point of the screen in a zoom view in iphone

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to add a box to the centre of the screen in a zoom view. E.g. if I move into an area of the content view and try using the offset coordinates, it becomes erratic if I zoom in or out. I can't seem to figure out the right mathematical formula for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a UIView or one of it's subclasses. You'll always have a center property available for you. That property is a CGPoint and you can do something like this to test if it is the required result you seek:

```
CGPoint center = [YourUIViewOrSubclass center];

NSLog(@"Center x is '%f' and y is '%f', center.c, center.y);
```

I hope this helps you. Otherwise try and rephrase your question and include a little context.